# Loading qm files within dynamic translation in Qt

Tags: qt, language-translation

I have an application that I want to translate the UI for Persian language. For that, I need to load **qt_fa.qm** and **my_app_fa.qm** in it. But the misfortune is, both files aren't loaded correctly. Below code always run as I expected:

```
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  QTranslator translator;
  translator.load("qt_fa");            // returns true
  app.installTranslator(&translator);

  translator.load("my_app_fa");        // returns true
  app.installTranslator(&translator);
   .
   .
```

sometimes the **qt_fa** affects the application and the layout is changed to RTL and the translation of Qt used words are displayed and none of my own translations are shown.

Sometimes the **my_app_fa** affects the app and just my own translations are displayed.

Do have any idea about the reason?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

According to Qt [Documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/internationalization.html) with the sample code snippet you should create **two** objects from **QTranslator**

```
int main()
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QTranslator qtTranslator;
    qtTranslator.load("qt_" + QLocale::system().name(),
            QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::TranslationsPath));
    app.installTranslator(&qtTranslator);

    QTranslator myappTranslator;
    myappTranslator.load("myapp_" + QLocale::system().name());
    app.installTranslator(&myappTranslator);

    ...
    return app.exec();
}
```